# Indexing PostgreSQL JSONB Array Elements

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, database-indexes

Like the title says, how can I index a JSONB array?

The contents look like...

```
["some_value", "another_value"]
```

I can easily access the elements like...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data->>0 = 'some_value';
```

I created an index like so...

```
CREATE INDEX table_data_idx ON table USING gin ((data) jsonb_path_ops);
```

When I run EXPLAIN, I still see it sequentially scanning...

What am I missing on indexing an array of text elements?

Comment: Do you want to support the condition `data->>0 = '...'` with that index or something else?

Comment: I want to support every element that could possibly exist in that dynamical length array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support that exact query with an index, the index would have to look like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ON "table" ((data->>0));
```

If you want to use the index you have, you cannot limit the search to just a specific array element (in your case, the first). You can speed up a search for `some_value` *anywhere* in the array:

```
SELECT * FROM "table"
WHERE data @> '["some_value"]'::jsonb;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach. I am still having problems getting the search to work using a JSONB Type, so I ended up switching my column to a `varchar ARRAY`

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    data varchar ARRAY NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX table_data_idx ON table USING GIN (data);

SELECT * FROM table WHERE data @> '{some_value}';
```

This works and is using the index.

---

I think my problem with my JSONB approach is because the element is actually nested much further and being treated as text.

i.e. `data->'some_key'->>'array_key'->>0`

And everytime I try to search I get all sorts of invalid token errors and other such things.

Comment: Maybe you should think about completely normalizing your model?

Comment: I solved the problem by moving the elements I needed to access out to a top-level column of type varchar ARRAY. All is good now.

Comment: You could have used `jsonb` with a query like that: `WHERE data @> '{"some_key": {"array_key": ["some_value"] } }'::jsonb`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to create a materialized view that has the primary key (or other unique index of your table) and expands the array field into a text column with the jsonb_array_elements_text function:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW table_mv
AS
SELECT DISTINCT table.id, 
jsonb_array_elements_text(data->0) AS array_elem FROM table;
```

You can then create a unique index on this materialized view (primary keys are not supported on materialized views):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_array_idx ON table_mv(id, array_elem);
```

Then query with a join to the original table on its primary key:

```
SELECT * FROM table INNER JOIN table_mv 
ON table.id = table_mv.id WHERE table_mv.array_elem = 'some_value';
```

This query should use the unique index and then look up the primary key of the original table, both very fast.